# Using inequality of Fisher for proving theorem about subsets.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $F$ be a set of subsets of an $n$-element set satisfying the following
properties:

1. $\forall A \in F : |A|\equiv 1 \pmod2 $.
2. $\forall A , B \in F : A\ne B \implies |A\cap B| \equiv 0\pmod2$.

Prove that $|F| \leqslant n$.

I tried to use inequality of Fisher to prove it, but I don't know how to do it. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder if it's useful to notice that $|A\cup B|\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ as well, since $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.